# Python struct.pack() not working in script

Tags: python, struct

I have some problems here when I try to use struct.pack from a script. Everything is fine in the interpreter:

```
>>> import struct  
>>> k=2  
>>> struct.pack(">b", k)  
'\x02'
```

Now when I do the same from a script I have problems:

```
k=2  
p =  struct.pack(">b", k)  
print "p is %s"%(p,)  
return p
```

Result:

```
p is
```

what am I doing wrong? I really don't understand this and would be glad if somebody could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Everything is fine. The character is unprintable.

```
print "p is %r" % (p,)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interpreter it is displaying the `repr` of that char and it is interpreting it when you do a print. So you can just do `repr(p)` in your script if you want to have same result as the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually printing character `'\x02`' which is not visible. Try printing it's representation instead.

```
print "p is %r"%(p,)
```